# How to upload my files to another server using multer in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, ftp, multer

```
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
              destination: function (req, file, callback) {

                callback(null, '/var/www/html');

              },
              filename: function (req, file, callback) {
              //console.log(file);return;
                if (file.mimetype == 'audio/mp3' || file.mimetype == 'audio/wav') {
                    var w = file.originalname;
                    var f = x.substr(0, x.lastIndexOf('.'));
                    callback(null, Date.now()+'-'+w);
                 }else{

                    var result = new sResultSh.commandResult("Failed","404");
                    onComplete(result);
                }
              },

            });
var upload = multer({ storage: storage}).any();
               upload(req, res, function (err) {
                if(err){
                    var resultErr =[];
                    resultErr.push(err);
                    var result = new sResultSh.commandResult("Failed","404",resultErr);
                    onComplete(result);

                }
                else{
                  var result = new sResultSh.commandResult("Success","200",);
                    onComplete(result);
                }
               })
```

Above is my code and i need to upload my file to 195.158.1.45/var/www/html..
How to do this in nodejs?
my file upload is successful in my local system but i need to upload my file to another server ?
help?

Answer (score 2):

Uploading Files to remote server using multer is not possible directly, But we can play around with  `multer-sftp, scp, ssh` techniques in node js

Check this answers using [multer-sftp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47292000/8326217) and [scp2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47288660/8326217)