# how to copy files to remote server using scp2 in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, scp, multer

I want to copy the files from local server to remote server in Node js using `scp2` package.  First of all.. Files uploaded to local server using `multer` after that copy or move that files to remote server.

My Code:

```
exports.newFileUpload =  function(req , res , next){

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
         cb(null, 'uploads/');
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
          var datetimestamp = Date.now();
          cb(null,  datetimestamp+ '-' +file.originalname);
      }
  });
        var upload = multer({ storage: storage, limits: { fieldSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024 }}).array('file');
        upload(req,res,function(err){
                console.log(req.body);
                console.log(req.files);
            if(err){
                res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
                console.log("Error Occured", err);
                return;
            }else{


                client.scp(req.files[0].path, {
                    host: 'www.do********.in',
                    username: 'username',
                    password: '*********',
                    path: '/uploads/'
                }, function(err) {
                    console.log(req.files[0].path);
                    console.log("files uploaded in remote server");
                    res.json({error_code:0,err_desc:null});
                });
            }
        });
}
```

file upload to local server is perfectly working, after that to remote server throwing error

Error:

```
{ date: 'Mon Nov 13 2017 01:00:22 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)',
  process:
   { pid: 5664,
     uid: null,
     gid: null,
     cwd: 'D:\\sample',
     execPath: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
     version: 'v8.2.1',
     argv: [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe', 'D:\\sample\\app.js' ],
     memoryUsage:
      { rss: 69619712,
        heapTotal: 45162496,
        heapUsed: 39166256,
        external: 149849 } },
  os: { loadavg: [ 0, 0, 0 ], uptime: 3537.1088452 },
  trace:
   [ { column: 11,
       file: 'util.js',
       function: 'Object.exports._errnoException',
       line: 1024,
       method: '_errnoException',
       native: false },
     { column: 20,
       file: 'util.js',
       function: 'exports._exceptionWithHostPort',
       line: 1047,
       method: '_exceptionWithHostPort',
       native: false },
     { column: 14,
       file: 'net.js',
       function: 'TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]',
       line: 1150,
       method: 'afterConnect [as oncomplete]',
       native: false } ],
  stack:[ 'Error: Can\'t set headers after they are sent.',
     '    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:504:11)',
     '    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:511:3)',
     '    at ServerResponse.header (D:\\sample\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\response.js:730:10)',
     '    at ServerResponse.send (D:\\sample\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\response.js:170:12)',
     '    at ServerResponse.json (D:\\sample\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\response.js:256:15)',
     '    at D:\\sample\\routes\\part.js:302:10',
     '    at Client.closeHandler (D:\\sample\\node_modules\\scp2\\lib\\scp.js:48:13)',
     '    at emitNone (events.js:105:13)',
     '    at Client.emit (events.js:207:7)',
     '    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\\sample\\node_modules\\scp2\\lib\\client.js:88:10)',
     '    at emitNone (events.js:105:13)',
     '    at Client.emit (events.js:207:7)',
     '    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\\sample\\node_modules\\ssh2\\lib\\client.js:225:10)',
     '    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)',
     '    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)',
     '    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:549:12)' ] }
```

Couldn't able to identify the error, awaiting  suggestions or possible ways to solve the problem.

*Thanks in Advance !*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uploading Files to remote server using `multer` is not possible directly, But we can play around with `multer-sftp, scp, ssh` techniques Methodologies

When Uploading Files to remote server using Node Js, We need to take care few things

1. Username and password should be correct
2. The Corresponding port number should be open in remote server
3. The Remote Directory Should have Write Access

Working Code using scp2 to move the files to remote server:

```
exports.newFileUpload =  function(req , res , next){

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
         cb(null, 'uploads/');
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
          var datetimestamp = Date.now();
          cb(null,  datetimestamp+ '-' +file.originalname);
      }
  });
        var upload = multer({ storage: storage, limits: { fieldSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024 }}).array('file');
        upload(req,res,function(err){
                console.log(req.body);
                console.log(req.files);
            if(err){
                res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
                console.log("Error Occured", err);
                return;
            }else{


                client.scp(req.files[0].path, {
                    host: 'host',
                    username: 'username',
                    password: '*********',
                    path: '/uploads/'
                }, function(err) {
                    console.log(req.files[0].path);
                    console.log("files uploaded in remote server");
                });
            }
        });
}
```

Note: Should install required packages as well as declare require things in code.

References: [multer-sftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-sftp), [scp2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scp2) , [node-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh)