# How to automate deploy of simple Vue WebApp (no server required)? (i.e. simple build chain with vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, continuous-integration, npm-scripts

I have written a small Vue app and have been looking for a nice way to automate its deployment, i.e. call lint -> test -> build -> upload to some web space (stage and /or production) (sftp). Basically a simple CI/CD pipeline.

I looked a task runners such as grunt (seems to be a bit [outdated](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-NPM-Bower-Grunt-Gulp-Webpack-Browserify-Slush-Yeoman-and-Express) and the docs didn't help me much) and gulp (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39825582/1480587)) and also thought of defining a npm script. CI tools such as Jenkins seem to be a bit oversized with some work to setup.

The npm script would probably be the simples solution, especially as I could simply chain lint / test / build:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --modern",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "prettier": "prettier --write src/**/*.{ts,js,vue,css,less,scss,html,json,md} public/**/*.{ts,js,vue,css,less,scss,html,json,md} test/**/*.{js,vue,css,less,scss,html,json,md} build/*.js",
    "deploy": "# ...?",
    "pipeline": "yarn lint && yarn prettier && yarn test && yarn build && yarn deploy"
  },
```

However, I've no good idea yet for an easy way to deploy the build to my web server. For grunt I found some tasks that might fit ([grunt-rsync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-rsync), [grunt-sftp-deploy](https://github.com/thrashr888/grunt-sftp-deploy)). But grunt doesn't seem to be the first choice nowadays.

Does anyone have any recommendations or suggestions?

Additional info: I'm using Windows and I don't want to publish my source (in this case) on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to deploy static site is to use pages.github.com - just push your build in github repo.

Another simple (Mega simple) service is [netlify](https://app.netlify.com/drop) - just install it with `npm install netlify-cli -g`. [Details in docs](https://www.netlify.com/docs/cli/)

But if you need better CI you don't need to search "vue deploy', you need any CI service from github, bitbucket, gitlab, etc. For example - [easy introduction by circleci](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/getting-started/)

---

Back to *your* question - do you use linux/mac or windows? 
It's very simple on linux, just use command like `scp from/local/dir to@remote/dir`. On windows you maybe should try some nodejs alternatives like snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47288660/7829041)

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer, I extend my question above: I'm using Windows and I don't want to publish my source (in this case) on github. I'll have a look at netlify and the mentioned answer.

Comment: You may not deploy sources on github or anything if you don't want. You always can push only *dist* (or whatever your build folder named) with minified build and *index.html* in root. After that for github all you need to set 

`> Click on the Settings tab and scroll down to the GitHub Pages section.
> Then select the master branch source and click on the Save button.`